# Handle i18n localization in alloy appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

these do not work in alloy:

```
<Label id="label2" onClick="doClick" title="L('helloWorld')" />
<Label id="label2" onClick="doClick" >L('helloWorld')</Label>
```

my translation files  are in:

```
/i18n/en/strings.xml
/i18n/fr/strings.xml
```

my `strings.xml` file has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="helloWorld">Hello World</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: i got the answer! you can close this thread.

Comment: If you have the answer, please answer your own question and accept that answer so that others can find it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ios simulator 8.1 is broken. localization in ios8.1 simulator doesn't work. test on real device.